# Memory leak with Spring-Batch

Tags: java, spring, memory-leaks, spring-batch

We have a spring-batch job responsible for loading test scenarios from a flat file into DB, running a program that we want to test, verifying its results.

We check many scenarios for the executions of the program (~300), so we load the precise scenario, launch the program and verify its results ~300 times.

The job is implemented as follow:

```
<job id="jobXY" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="loadFlatFileToDb" next="loadTestScenario">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="flatFileReader" writer="flatFileWriter" commit-interval="2500"/>
        </tasklet>
    </step>

    <step id="loadTestScenario" next="launchProgram">
        <tasklet ref="loadTestScenario"/>
    </step>

    <step id="launchProgram" next="verifyResults">
        <tasklet ref="launchProgramTasklet"/>
    </step>

    <step id="verifyResults" next="endTest">
        <tasklet ref="verifieAvisTasklet"/>
    </step>

    <decision id="endTest" decider="endTestDecider">
        <next on="FALSE" to="loadTestScenario" />
        <end on="TRUE"/>
    </decision>
</job>
```

We loop over the last 4 steps 300 times.  Those steps are really lights in term of memory consumption. In addition, the program tested is launched in another JVM. So it should not impact this program in terms of memory.

However, the memory taken by this program increases over the times. After ~150 executions the memory (at start: ~100mo) used is 5 times bigger and increases up to 5go!

By connecting Yourkit profiler, I was able to detect that the StepExecution stored in the context use a lot of memory (and this increase after each loop turn).

How can I disable the feature which saves the StepExecution after each step? I don't need it as my job is not restartable.

If you have any other idea which could resolve my problem, I'm also interested.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: How can you say that there is memory  leak ? Did you try to tune your JVM configuration

Comment: I say it because according to what the program does, there's no reason it takes up to 5go. In addition, as long as it runs, the memory used increases. I often end up with "outofmemoryerror gc overhead limit exceeded" errors. When I extend the memory available to the JVM it works, but it is not a good solution.

Comment: what are your components really doing? maybe you are preventing the GC to get rid of Objects your components created?

Comment: I have analyzed the code and I don't feel like the object are not able to be released by my own code (but I can be wrong of course). However, the analyze with Yourkit proves that the biggest objects are the StepExecution stored by spring in the context.

Comment: Create the dump of the jvm when the out of memory arise and see which objects are using the maximum memory.

Comment: As I said, I did that and the biggest objects are the StepExecution of the Spring Batch's context

Comment: do you have any progress on this issue ?

Comment: Not much, unfortunately. As a workaround we run several time the program with a subset of inputs rather than one with everything.